# Criteria with join is fine... but if I want to add a condition?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've the following schema:

```
TABLE EMPLOYEE           TABLE COUNTRY
---------------         ---------------
id                 |------> id
name               |        country_name
country_id   ------|        country_code
```

If I want to retrieve all the employees belonging to a country I use a criteria like this:

```
Criteria crit =  getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("country.id", countryId));
List<Employee> employees = crit.list();
```

My employee entity refers to country in this way:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    private Country country;

    // Other stuff here 
}
```

Everything here works fine!

The problem is if I don't know the countryId, but I have the country_code instead(i.g. "UK"). How should I change the criteria above so that I can join the tables and add the restriction on the country code?

Comment: You can use if else on the values (ie if blank) and include the crit.add(Restrictions.eq("country.id", countryId)) inside the block, depending on the result of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Criteria criteria =  getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class,"e");
     criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
     criteria.createAlias("e.country", "c");        
     Criterion codeId= Restrictions.eq("c.id", yourCountryId);
     Criterion codeCriterion= Restrictions.eq("c.countryCode", yourCountryCode);
     criteria.add(Restrictions.or(codeId, codeCriterion));

     List<Employee> employees = criteria.list();
```

**OR**

```
    Criteria criteria =  getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
    Criterion codeId = Restrictions.eq("country.id", yourCountryId);
    Criterion codeCriterion = Restrictions.eq("country.countryCode", yourCountryCode);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(codeId, codeCriterion));

    List<Employee> employees = crit.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way, simple add if else

```
Criteria crit =  getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);

if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(countryId))
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("country.id", countryId));
else
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("country.code", countryCode));

List<Employee> employees = crit.list();
```