# How to set placeholders in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi this my java code here am using hibernate to check whether this email id and password exist in db or not could anybody plz exp line me how to place the value to this place holders.

```
Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String query;
            query = "from RegisterPojo where email=? and pwd=? ";
            List<RegBean> list = ses.createQuery(query).list();

            ses.close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the `Query` class' javadoc?

Comment: i have those values inside bean but i don't know how to place in those place holders..

Comment: sorry am not aware of that ..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```
 Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      String query = "from RegisterPojo rp where rp.email = :emailAddress and rp.pwd = :password";
      List<RegisterPojo> list = ses.createQuery(query)
      .setParameter("emailAddress", Your email address)
      .setParameter("password", Your password)
      .list();
      ses.close();
```

Comment: can i check my list is empty or not like this if (list.isEmpty()) thank u

Comment: @user2838630 yes you can do.

Comment: @Prabhakaran how do I use that using Criteria?

Comment: @Dener please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536382/criteria-with-join-is-fine-but-if-i-want-to-add-a-condition/18536727#18536727

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your query like this,

```
 query = "from RegisterPojo where email =:email and pwd =:password ";

 List<RegisterPojo> list = ses.createQuery(query)
 .setParameter("email",emailVal)
 .setParameter("password",emailVal)
 .list();
```

[Read the hql docs here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a  prepared statement instead of a string. [example here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)

```
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement  ("from RegisterPojo where email=? and pwd=?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "email");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            String query;
            query = "from RegisterPojo where email=? and pwd=? ";
            List<RegBean> list = ses.createQuery(query).setParameter(0,emailVal).setParameter(1,emailVal).list();

            ses.close();
```

Comment: I think RegBean need to rename to RegisterPojo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
   Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      String query = "from RegisterPojo where email = '" + varEmailAddress + "' and pwd = '" + varPassword + "'";
      List<RegisterPojo> list = ses.createQuery(query).list();
  ses.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry This Is not Answer but instead another case, in above case @Grigoriev Nick suggested

```
 query = "from RegisterPojo where email=? and pwd=? ";
            List<RegBean> list = ses.createQuery(query).setParameter(0,emailVal).setParameter(1,emailVal).list();
```

but here the script starts with directly ***from*** clause while what if I want want to used sql like below

```
  WITH A (
    /// do some selection from many tables using various union as per my requirement
  ),
   B (
   ///  another set of sqls for different set of data
   )
select XXX from A a join B b on a.XYZ = b.xyz
where 
    /// few more fixed where clause conditions
   AND A.SOME_COLUMN = ?  // Here Instead Of String Concatenation I want to 
//use Query parameters but using hibernate instead of raw Prepares statements
```

Comment: Please post working solutions to OP's query. May/Might working solutions does not help.

Comment: @mishsx 1  I know tht I should provide solution but i just do not wanted to duplicate the question if that needed I will do that as well